# How to run nodejs app as service with forever or upstart?

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am running my app as below

```
NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets 'react,es2015' src/server.js
```

How to run it as service with forever or upstart?

Comment: Which OS are you running this in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) as a process manager.

by the way, 
with forever you should create a `forever.[environment].json` that forever uses as a configuration file:

```js
[
  {
    // App2
    "uid": "app2",
    "append": true,
    "watch": true,
    "script": "index.js",
    "sourceDir": "/home/myuser/app2",
    "args": ["--port", "8081"] // CLI ARGS HERE
  }
]
```

Comment: I tried with PM2 I get error in log as below:                                                            SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)

Comment: thats because you didn't traspiled your code, it not depends on PM2 or FOREVER. With PM2: `pm2 start --interpreter babel-node index.js`. Try to follow this guide: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/using-transpilers-with-pm2

Comment: I get error with installing babel-node  npm install -g babel-node  "You tried to install babel-node. This is not babel-node │You should npm install -g babel-cli instead "

Comment: that's because the package is `babel-cli`. follow what they say :) install babel-cli

Comment: Installed with npm install -g babel-cli and then npm install -g babel-node, but still same error.

Comment: Error also says Failed at the babel-node@6.5.2 postinstall script 'node message.js; sleep 10; exit 1;'.

Comment: you get `babel-node` by installing `babel-cli`, so, all what you need is to install `babel-cli`.

Comment: I installed babel-cli 6.18.0 but still with pm2 same error SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Comment: what `babel plugins` are you using? Are you sure that `babel-plugin-transform-imports` is correctly working?

Comment: I have babel-plugin-transform-imports@1.1.0 installed globally

Comment: follow the guide http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/using-transpilers-with-pm2 and be sure that babel loads that plugin.